# Location of *.d.ts inconsistencies

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

When looking through my node_modules to see what packages have type definitions, some .d.ts files are in @types/, while other are housed as index.d.ts within their respective package. Why is that?

Comment: if you installed package typings as `npm i -D @types/some-package-name` then its located under the `node_modules/@types/some-package-name` as its holds only types of that module. But some modules supports typescript in-built and can be accessed to types without addition @types installation

Comment: Some package would choose to upload `.d.ts` files together with the `.js` files while others choose to upload `.d.ts` files in separate `@types/*` packages. It's just a matter of choice.

Comment: Also it could be that library's author wrote it in JS and didn't add any types, either because they don't know, don't use TS or just didn't feel like it, and some other people decided to type a module. They then uploaded their type definitions to `DefinitelyTyped` which is this packages under `@types/*` and now the module is typed